# Need Windows XP alternative to GetNamedPipeClientProcessId

Tags: c++, named-pipes

The code below is working superbly, but now I want to generalize it, as `GetNamedPipeClientProcessID` is only compatible with Windows Vista and above. **What alternative options do I have that support windows XP?**

```
bRet = GetNamedPipeClientProcessId(hIn, &ClientID);
if (FALSE == bRet)
{
        printf("\nGetNamedPipeClientProcessId FAILED\n");
    CloseHandle(Overlapped.hEvent);
    CloseHandle(hIn);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can do much in that case. What I would suggest is showing a clear warning to the end-user stating that unless they upgrade to a secure operating system (which XP is not) your software will not be able to provide a secure communication. Then it will be up to the end-user to decide.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you handle the protocol, when the connection is established send a packet with the process id and read it in the other endpoint.

Comment: thanks man.....but i want to identify the client before he sends something and after he connects......

Comment: As far as I remember there is no way of doing this. Named pipes are implemented internally like a `File System` and most api's to get pipe info are wrappers to `NtQueryInformationFile` calls. In Vista they added the query to retrieve the process id which is stored in an kernel structure.

Comment: @MauroH.Leggieri: Unless you implement encryption and have a secure communication channel (which, to the best of my knowledge, is not possible with named pipes on Windows) sending a client process ID in the packet is a terrible idea prone to MITM attack.

Comment: @ahmd0 he does not mention if he uses encryption or not but it is out of the context of the question.

Comment: @MauroH.Leggieri: That is why suggesting to send client process ID, presumably via an insecure channel, is a **very bad** idea. That was my point.